# Are prepositional-case prepositions obligatory? (Is it possible to have the prepositional case without a preposition?)

Tags: предлоги

I know that technically, the prepositional (предложный) case is only used for objects of four prepositions: в (in), на (on), при (in presence of / at time of), and по (upon). However, can the prepositions be elided, for example, in dialog?

```
- О ком вы говорили?
- Маше.
```

To my non-native ear this sounds strange, but I wonder what native speakers would say. Can you provide good, natural-sounding examples where the prepositional case is used without a preposition?

Answer (score 5):

No, as the name suggests, the modern prepositional case used with prepositions always. That wasn't so in old times, when there was *a locative case*, not *a prepositional one*. That is, all "natural-sounding" examples are about 500-900 years old.

> Солнце ему тъмою путь заступаше;
>   нощь стонущи ему грозою птичь убуди, свистъ звѣринъ въ стазби;
>   дивъ кличетъ *връху древа*... (i.e. *at the top of the tree*)

What still remains in modern language is considered to be *adverbs*, like

> Я возвёл очи *горе́* --> I looked at the sky

Here *горе́* actually means *to the hill / mountain* in a prepositionless form of locative case, but from the point of view of modern grammar it's *an adverb*.

Comment: The text you quoted is not Russian language (even not old Russian).

Comment: @Anixx - That's from _The Tale of Igor's Campaign_. What language do you think it was written in?

Answer (score 4):

This short-form answer (actually, dative case without additional context) to a question in prepositional case is *impossible*, it should be "О Маше". However, it is possible to answer indirectly - with an extended sentence where the subject in question is mentioned in any other case (dative here).

```
- О ком вы говорили?

- Маше отдавали должное - всё никак забыть её (выходку) не можем.
```

Sometimes a short indirect answer without a preposition can substitute for the subject meant in prepositional case:

```
- На чём поедешь, на телеге или в карете?

- Верхом (= на лошади, на ишаке).
```